# Can "at least by" be used to mean "latest by"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Can you use "at least by" to mean "latest by"?

> 1. Could you return the book **at least by** February 1?
> 2. Could you return the book **latest by** February 1?

Do these two mean the same thing? Does either one have correct syntax?

Comment: #1 is potentially ambiguous (for example, it might imply *Even if you don't actually **buy** the book, can you at least **return** it by Feb?*). #2 is ungrammatical. Most native speakers would probably say *Could you return the book by February 1 **at the latest**?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **At least** *phrase*
>   1 Not less than; at the minimum:
>   ‘clean the windows at least once a week’
>   2 If nothing else (used to add a positive comment about a generally negative situation):
>   ‘the options aren't complete, but at least they're a start’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_least)
>
> **By** *preposition*
>   4 Indicating a deadline or the end of a particular time period:
>   ‘I've got to do this report by Monday’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)

If read literally with *at least* specifying a restriction on the date, #1 is meaningless. *At least* (definition 1 above) specifies the minimum, so since it is a 'least date', any later date should be fine. However, *by* in that context specifies an upper bound on the date. Together, they 'restrict' the due date to any date before (*cf* by) any date after (*cf* at least) 1 February. That is, the due date is completely unspecified.

Alternatively, one can argue that *at least* doesn't apply to the date. Depending on which words are stressed, it might apply to *return* or *the book*.

FumbleFingers addresses the first in his [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116882/can-at-least-by-be-used-to-mean-latest-by#comment236056_116882) below your question:

> #1 is potentially ambiguous (for example, it might imply Even if you don't actually buy the book, can you at least **return** it by Feb?). ...

This reading conveys a sense of exasperation, something along the lines of: *at least return it (by the deadline); don't just throw it away*.

Applying *at least* to *the book* produces a slightly different request. There may have been some negotiation for the borrower to review the book, and for the review to accompany the book's return by the deadline. However, even if the review (or whatever) cannot be produced by the deadline, the speaker requests that (at least) the book itself be returned then.

That is, *at least* is applied to *return*, not to the date (see definition 2 above). Returning the book by the due date is then the least requirement. The borrower is free to do more, such as provide a book review when returning the book. However, this doesn't make your #1 and #2 sentences equivalent. #1 would include #2, but #2 loses the sense of 'doing more' in #1.

You ask:

> Can you use "at least by" to mean "latest by"?
>   ...
>   Do these two mean the same thing? Does either one have correct syntax?

No, "at least by" doesn't have the same meaning as "latest by". The two sentences convey different ideas, though it is possible to consider #2 to be included in #1. Both sentences are somewhat awkward. Since "by" already includes the notion of a deadline, you can drop "at least" and "latest":

- Could you return the book by February 1?

Comment: ```This reading conveys a sense of exasperation, something along the lines of: at least return it (by the deadline); don't just throw it away.``` Yes it does seem to convey this sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your two phrases have slightly different meanings

> at least by
>   You need to return the book **at least by** Friday or there will be a fine.
>   *you need to return the book, possibly before Friday, or there will be a fine*

means "possibly by", it suggests the possibility of missing a deadline

> at the latest by
>   You need to return the book **at the latest by** Friday or there will be a fine.
>   *you must return the book by Friday or there will be a fine*

means "definitely by", deadline should  not be missed

To make them equivalent, one might use

> at least by..., but not later than...